# Flutter - How to check if a SingleChildScrollView fits in a screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Is it possible to check if a **SingleChildScrollView** fits in a screen so it doesn't need scrolling?

I want to achieve different behaviours based on this information.

Thanks to everyone in advance.

Comment: nope, the sizing is done later so you cannot predict the future ;-(

Comment: if your content is less than available space then singlechildscrollview will not allow to scroll.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, and found a way around this. Here's how I made it:

### *Theory*:

You need to provide a [scroll controller](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController-class.html) to your `SingleChildScrollView`.

The reason is that the "[...] scroll controller creates a [ScrollPosition](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollPosition-class.html) to manage the state specific to an individual Scrollable widget", and we'll use exactly that to determine if the contents of our scrollable widget fits in the screen.

The property we're interested in is `maxScrollExtent`. It belongs to the `ScrollPosition`, and indicates the "maximum in-range value for pixels" that we can scroll to.

### *How*:

The way I used it was to check if this value is greater than zero:

- If so, then the contents **do not** fit in the given height.
- Otherwise, if it's **equal to zero**, then the contents of the scrollable fits the screen.

### *Caveats in using this approach*:

The child's size is a reflex of the build, so you can't know *in advance* if it will be scrollable or not. But what we *can* do is add a [post frame callback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html) to be executed after the build. By that point, when this callback is run, the build has already occurred, so we can check if the child fits in the screen or not.

Problem is, we need a `StatefulWidget` to do so. In that, we can schedule a post frame callback either in the `initState()` override - which will run only once during the widget's lifecycle, or in `didChangeDependencies()` - which runs whenever the widget needs rebuilding due a dependency change. See what fits best to your purpose.

### *TL;DR:*

Here's a sample that shows how to take advantage of `maxScrollExtent`. Try running it in a [flutter dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/flutter) and change the width of the preview:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Here's the important widget
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  final ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();
  
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        // Checks to see the controller's [ScrollMetrics] maxScrollExtent.
        // If zero, then the entire scrollable fits in the screen's viewport.
        // So, triggers fadeoutController.reverse() to make scrollbar go away.
        var maxScrollExtent = _controller.position.maxScrollExtent;
        if (maxScrollExtent == 0) {
          print('Fits entirely');
        } else {
          print('Needs scrolling');
        }
      });
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
        controller: _controller,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: Text(_text),
            ),
          ],
        ),
    );
  }
}

// very, very long lorem ipsum so that we can get to scroll if it doesn't fit.
const String _text = '''Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam semper, massa ac dignissim elementum, sapien nibh faucibus nibh, vel fermentum justo augue non est. Vestibulum at diam a orci hendrerit pellentesque vitae et tortor. Donec vel ultricies ipsum. Morbi eleifend dolor eget risus dignissim tempor. Curabitur suscipit eros turpis, id iaculis odio fringilla nec. Phasellus ullamcorper lacus nec dapibus euismod. Aenean convallis euismod pellentesque. Integer congue libero in turpis dapibus, vitae condimentum ex elementum. Nullam condimentum, turpis eget tincidunt ultrices, orci mi maximus ex, sit amet tempor nulla mi quis libero. Sed congue elementum magna, ut luctus felis congue ut. Aliquam fringilla tortor at elit tempus venenatis. Quisque porta commodo nisi, sit amet rhoncus arcu dapibus non. Nam sit amet ullamcorper dui. Quisque dui dolor, tincidunt in urna sit amet, ultricies egestas libero.

Sed at lorem magna. Sed dignissim ullamcorper convallis. Nunc ornare, urna eget sodales feugiat, sem odio eleifend felis, a blandit lorem mi sed orci. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque sed mi scelerisque, sollicitudin nunc non, ullamcorper neque. Quisque purus magna, lacinia vel ex a, tempor viverra ante. Phasellus volutpat nulla nec aliquet sollicitudin. Morbi ultricies dapibus scelerisque. Pellentesque ut elit justo. Phasellus eget tempus massa. Curabitur id enim mollis, rutrum lorem in, aliquet diam. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Proin semper ultricies orci. Nunc tempor fermentum dolor, placerat aliquam arcu ullamcorper sed. Cras eleifend erat gravida, mattis dolor eu, mollis lorem. Donec eu aliquet mauris, a egestas tortor.

Vivamus eu lorem erat. Phasellus condimentum quam quam, semper mattis odio dapibus vitae. Nulla eleifend lectus malesuada sem feugiat elementum. Phasellus semper luctus sodales. Aenean facilisis eu purus eget ultricies. Mauris non hendrerit lectus. Donec mollis ante non viverra euismod. Nulla aliquam, quam a rutrum dictum, tortor magna sagittis diam, non pulvinar erat nibh id nibh. Aliquam rutrum, mauris sit amet eleifend convallis, orci arcu egestas purus, vel dignissim tellus quam sit amet dolor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Etiam justo orci, sagittis a arcu vitae, viverra fringilla nunc. Maecenas ac semper ligula. Suspendisse ultrices tellus placerat nisl euismod pharetra.

Quisque et tellus ut magna efficitur volutpat ut nec metus. Vestibulum sed turpis id justo porta sagittis vitae et ligula. Aliquam ultricies tortor nulla, laoreet efficitur dui dictum eget. Aenean at ante a odio ornare pharetra in eget metus. Fusce vulputate luctus tortor in convallis. Praesent a velit libero. Proin molestie condimentum commodo. Nullam congue massa a odio congue, a bibendum tortor vestibulum. Etiam pellentesque dapibus libero. Donec iaculis vitae ante luctus varius.

Donec eleifend, elit eget accumsan rhoncus, diam nunc luctus dui, eu accumsan arcu sapien sed urna. Vivamus non viverra tellus, eget tincidunt nisl. Suspendisse nec laoreet risus. Vestibulum sit amet est elit. Duis vestibulum maximus magna ut dignissim. Mauris suscipit fermentum sapien sit amet finibus. Morbi quis lectus tincidunt nibh malesuada auctor non at neque. Fusce in tortor dictum, ornare felis ut, fermentum justo. Nulla ullamcorper viverra bibendum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris et neque in purus auctor bibendum. Proin posuere enim id egestas scelerisque. In sollicitudin velit a ex fringilla, nec vulputate arcu volutpat. Mauris euismod sapien justo, sit amet pulvinar nisl volutpat quis. Sed finibus, leo vel molestie porta, quam est placerat mauris, vitae placerat eros turpis porta lorem. Donec at tortor tortor.''';
```